# .htaccess redirect from subdomain folder to subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am new here. Please, can you help me?
My problem:
If someone goes to my website like this https://www.pinf.sk/_sub/AAAAA/foo/bar/rrr.php?ggg=123, I want to redirect him to http://AAAAA.pinf.sk/foo/bar/rrr.php?ggg=123

How can I do it? (it have to be dynamic, also work with /_sub/BBBB or /_sub/QWERTY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following `mod_rewrite` rule in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^\_sub\/([^\/]*)\/(.*) http://$1.pinf.sk/$2 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

**Key to the Regex Pattern Match above:**

`^` - Start of match

`\_sub` - Match any URI starting with `_sub`

`\/([^\/]*)\/` - Capture the name of the folder which immediately follows `/_sub/`.

**N.B.** `[^\/]*` means

> any character which *isn't* `/`, any number of times.

Placing this in parenthesis captures it.

`\/(.*)` - Capture all characters which follow the folder-name just captured.

**Key to the mod_rewrite Flags above:**

`L` - Last rule - don't process any more rules after this one

`R=301` - Make this a Permanent Redirect (301)

`QSA` - *Query String Append* (ie. whatever variables follow the ? in the original URI, include the `?` and the same variables at the end of the new URI)

Comment: Thank you. But there's problem. It's cycled! For example: http://tv.pinf.sk/. My actual HTACCESS: RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pinf\.sk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.pinf.sk/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^\_sub\/([^\/]*)\/(.*) http://$1.pinf.sk/$2 [L,R=301,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /www/p/i/u73214/public_html/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /www/p/i/u73214/public_html/500.php

Comment: Can you explain the problem in more detail, @user3129342? What do you mean when you write "It's cycled!"?